# Пояснение задачи на мегаинверсии

Tags: алгоритм

Есть задача из [контеста](https://ncpc.idi.ntnu.no/ncpc2011/ncpc2011problems.pdf).
Есть даже её [решение](https://github.com/Mortal/megainversions) с помощью деревьев Фенвика.

Решение корректное. Никак не пойму, какая взаимосвязь между мегаинверсиями и обычными инверсиями (строка 55 в коде по ссылке выше).

Мои рассуждения:

Первое дерево `numbers` напоминает сумму частот. Мы для очередного числа num в данной последовательности можем получить кол-во чисел, которые больше чем num `numbers.query(n)-numbers.query(num)`, т.е. кол-во инверсий числа num.

К примеру, есть последовательность `3 2 1 4`. После добавления в дерево чисел 3, 2, 1, для числа `1` мы быстро найдем кол-во инверсий этого числа, т.е. `2`.

Второе дерево, судя по названию, хранит сумму инверсий. Его назначение мне как раз и не ясно, т.к. не понимаю следующее действие:

```
megainversions += inversions.query(n)-inversions.query(num);
```

Которое по идее ищет ответ. Как надо рассуждать, чтобы прийти к такому умозаключению? Есть какая-то связь между обычными инверсиями и "мегаинверсиями"?

Comment: Лучше перенести текст задания и код в тело вопроса, так вопрос будет нагляднее и самодостаточнее.

Answer (score 1):

Тут простая связь:
Фенвик используется, чтобы отвечать на запросы: сколько чисел, больших моего текущего num, было добавлено ранее.
Дерево numbers используют, чтобы подсчитать обычные инверсии. Собственно, там по запросами видно: `numbers.query(n)-numbers.query(num)` дает все числа, большие num, которые были уже добавлены. Получается на итерации, в inversions на позицию num записывается количество обычных инверсий, которые заканчиваются элементом num на текущий момент.
Теперь, чтобы подсчитать количество мегаинверсий, давайте узнаем сколько инверсий получено ранее с значением больше num (как раз получится три элемента всего). А это как раз `inversions.query(n)-inversions.query(num)`.